# comparar dos inputs en Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hola vengo trabajando en el cambio de contraseña.
Necesito implemetar que el campo **`repita contraseña`** sea igual al campo **`Contraseña`**.

Pero si el usuario cambia el campo **`Contraseña`** le salga que las contraseñas no conciden, y de forma inversa si cambia el campo **`repita contraseña`** le salga el aviso, sin embargo si ambos coinciden que le salga el aviso "*Las constraseñas si coinciden"*

**Hasta el momento esto es mi avance**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mensaje_error').hide();  
});

$("#contra_n_usuario").keyup(function () {
    var cont = $('#contra_usuario').val();
    var cont2 = $('#contra_n_usuario').val();
    if (cont == cont2) {
        $('#mensaje_error').hide();
        $('#mensaje_error').attr("class", "control-label col-md-12 text-success");
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
        $('#mensaje_error').html("Las constraseñas si coinciden");
    } else {
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="form_configuracion" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="box-body">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-6">Usuario</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="nombre_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese codigo" required="" class="form-control" value="MOREDROID" type="text"><span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Rol</label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="rol_usuario" readonly="" class="form-control"  value="ADMINISTRADOR" type="text"><span class="help-block"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Contraseña</label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="contra_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese Nueva Contraseña" required="" class="form-control" type="password"> <span class="help-block"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-6">Repita Contraseña</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <input id="contra_n_usuario" placeholder="Repita Contraseña" required="" class="form-control" type="password"> <span class="help-block"></span>
        <label id="mensaje_error" class="control-label col-md-12 text-danger" style="display: block;">Las constraseñas no coinciden</label>
      </div>                                                        
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta es?

Comment: Deberías realizar cualquier validación de contraseñas en el servidor. En el cliente, es un fallo de seguridad.

Comment: Alejando, no tendría por qué validar esto en el servidor. Si fuera guardar la pass obvio que si, pero en este caso solo quiere que el user en repetir contraseña ponga la misma :P

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz es una validación de inputs no de contraseñas. Ya cuando implemente el botón ya pasará por el PHP y por ende por el servidor.

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores por favor, ¿puedes modificar el comentario para que no sea ofensivo?. Por mi parte se trataba de una sugerencia. Gracias!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te falta cambiar el texto del mensaje cuando hay un error y agregar la misma función al otro campo de contraseña

Agregas listeners:

```
    $("#contra_usuario").on('keyup', cambioDePass);
    $("#contra_n_usuario").on('keyup', cambioDePass);
```

Y la función cambioDePass:

```
var cambioDePass = function() {
        var cont = $('#contra_usuario').val();
    var cont2 = $('#contra_n_usuario').val();
    if (cont == cont2) {
        $('#mensaje_error').hide();
        $('#mensaje_error').attr("class", "control-label col-md-12 text-success");
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
        $('#mensaje_error').html("Las constraseñas si coinciden");
    } else {
         $('#mensaje_error').html("Las constraseñas no coinciden");
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
    }
}
```

Quedaría algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mensaje_error').hide();  
});

var cambioDePass = function() {
  var cont = $('#contra_usuario').val();
    var cont2 = $('#contra_n_usuario').val();
    if (cont == cont2) {
        $('#mensaje_error').hide();
        $('#mensaje_error').attr("class", "control-label col-md-12 text-success");
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
        $('#mensaje_error').html("Las constraseñas si coinciden");
    } else {
         $('#mensaje_error').html("Las constraseñas no coinciden");
        $('#mensaje_error').show();
    }
}

$("#contra_usuario").on('keyup', cambioDePass);
$("#contra_n_usuario").on('keyup', cambioDePass);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="form_configuracion" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="box-body">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-6">Usuario</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="nombre_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese codigo" required="" class="form-control" value="MOREDROID" type="text"><span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Rol</label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="rol_usuario" readonly="" class="form-control"  value="ADMINISTRADOR" type="text"><span class="help-block"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">Contraseña</label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
     <input id="contra_usuario" placeholder="Ingrese Nueva Contraseña" required="" class="form-control" type="password"> <span class="help-block"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-6">Repita Contraseña</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <input id="contra_n_usuario" placeholder="Repita Contraseña" required="" class="form-control" type="password"> <span class="help-block"></span>
        <label id="mensaje_error" class="control-label col-md-12 text-success" style="display: block;">Las constraseñas si coinciden</label>
      </div>                                                        
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>    
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a7t1rjx/)

Comment: Muchas, gracias, la respuesta brindad me resulto, por ende la pregunta queda como cerrara con su respectivo check espero mi foto a positivo, quizas mas adelante a alguien le sirva de ayuda (Y)